# Vuetify Dialog Reset Content on re-open

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js, renderer

I have a vuetify dialog that contains an iframe.

I need that every time the dialog re-opens the iframe will reset to the beginning.

Right now the with every opening of the dialog the iframe is at its last state.

I tried using v-if on the dialog and adding a :key for re-rendering and it didn't work.

my dialog + iframe

```
 <v-dialog
          v-model="dialog['dialog_' + index]"
          width="500">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;">
              <v-btn
                v-on="on"
                v-bind="attrs"
                @click="onActionClick(action)"
                icon
                class="action-button">
                <img :src="'../../../static/assets/Images/' + action.icon +'.svg'">
              </v-btn>
              <p
                class="mt-2"
                style="line-height: 12px">{{ action.label }}</p>
            </div>
          </template>
          <iframe
            :src="iframeUrl"
            :title="action.label"/>
        </v-dialog>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In your v-dialog component do this:

```html
<v-dialog
  @input="refreshIframe"
  v-model="dialog['dialog_' + index]"
  width="500">
```

And add a method to your script like this:

```js
methods: {
  // other methods...
  refreshIframe () {
    const tempUrl = this.iframeUrl;
    iframeUrl = "";
    iframeUrl = tempUrl;
  }
}
```